# Subtle inequality where induction seems not to work

Tags: inequality, induction

Let $p$ be a positive integer and $p \ge 2$. I want to show that 
$$
2(p/2)^{p/2} e^{-p/2} \le \sqrt{p} \Gamma(p/2),
$$
where $\Gamma(x) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t} ~ dt$ is known as Gamma function. I checked it on wolramalpha.com and its appeared to correct, see [this plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B2%28p%2F2%29%5E%28p%2F2%29+e%5E%28-p%2F2%29+%2F+%28sqrt%28p%29+Gamma%28p%2F2%29%29%2C+%7Bp%2C+2%2C+1000%7D%5D).

What I've tried: 
I tried to prove it by induction:

For $p=2$ its clear.

For $p$ we have $2(p/2)^{p/2} e^{-p/2} \le \sqrt{p} \Gamma(p/2)$ and want to prove for $p+1$: $2(p/2 + 1/2)^{p/2 + 1/2} e^{-p/2 - 1/2} \le \sqrt{p + 1} \Gamma(p/2 + 1/2)$.

So, for using the known result for $p$ I do the following:

$$
2(p/2 + 1/2)^{p/2 + 1/2} e^{-p/2 - 1/2} \le 2\sqrt{e \cdot \frac{p+1} 2} (p/2)^{p/2} e^{-p/2 - 1/2} = \sqrt{\frac{p+1} 2} 2(p/2)^{p/2} e^{-p/2},
$$
where in the first step I used $(1 + p^{-1})^{p/2} \le \sqrt{e}$. Then, using the induction assumption we have that we need to show 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{p+1} 2} \sqrt{p} \Gamma(p/2) \le \sqrt{p+1} \Gamma\bigg(\frac{p+1} 2\bigg),
$$
or, equivalentnly, 
$$
\sqrt{\frac p 2} \Gamma\bigg(\frac p 2\bigg) \le \Gamma\bigg(\frac{p+1} 2 \bigg),
$$
which seems to be wrong, see [the plot from here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bsqrt%28p%2F2%29+*+Gamma%28p%2F2%29+%2F+Gamma%28p%2F2+%2B+1%2F2%29%2C+%7Bp%2C+2%2C+10000%7D%5D).

Is the step $(1 + p^{-1})^{p/2} \le \sqrt{e}$ very rough? Are there any other possible approaches for proving the initial inequality?

Comment: Well, with all those "$/2$" in there, if I were to attempt induction I would do separately even and odd $p$, and for induction step go up by $2$.  On the other hand, $\Gamma$ is defined for real values, so why restrict $p$ to integer for that inequality?  If you prove it for real $p \ge 2$ then of course induction is probably not the method to use.

Comment: I suggest you take the log of both sides, and then try using the idea behind the Sterling approximation.

Comment: @GEdgar, for even $p$ (i.e. $p=2n$) it reduces to proving $\Gamma(n) \ge \sqrt{2} n^{n - 0.5} e^{-n}$, which is true, but induction (as in my approach above) gives the opposite inequality.

Comment: @user721481, the inequality is pretty subtle and approximation may not work since its basically an asymptotic approximation.